# What is the philisohopical difference between Gyan Yoga and Sankhya Yoga

Tags: bhagavad-gita, jnana, samkhya

Bhagwat Gita chapter 2 verse 39,

It is written as:

```
एषा तेऽभिहिता साङ्ख्ये
बुद्धिर्योगे त्विमां शृणु |
बुद्ध्या युक्तो यया पार्थ
कर्मबन्धं प्रहास्यसि || 39||
```

which is often translated as:

> Arjuna, this attitude of mind has been presented to you from the point of view of Jñāna yoga. Now hear the same as presented from the standpoint of Karmayoga...

--extracted from the Gita Press, Gorakhpur (The song Divine)

And also in Chapter 3, Verse 3, as Shree Krishna says:

> ज्ञानयोगेन साङ्ख्यानां

same the Gita Press, Gorakhpur (The song Divine) says:

> In the case of the Sankhyayogi, the Sadhana proceeds along the path of Knowledge;

Wikipedia says, `Jñāna, sometimes transcribed as gyaan, means "knowledge" in Sanskrit`.

So, Is `Sankhya Yog` and `Gyan Yoga` the same? Or there is any difference between them?

Comment: A bit loose translation by Gita Press (if it is from there), the term jñāna yoga doesn't even occur in the śloka, yet they still gave it in the translation, and thus it's causing a confusion to the reader.  Tbh, sāṅkhya used in the śloka is not exactly jñāna yoga. However, sāṅkhya is a component of jñāna yoga, so the translation is not exactly incorrect, but it still isn't literal and deviates from exact meaning. I have seen the commentaries of Madhva, Rāmānuja, Madhusūdana and Abhinavagupta, but none of them say jñāna yoga on 2.39, instead they explain what sāṅkhya means in this śloka.

Comment: Sāṅkhya used in Bhagavad Gītā either refers to the philosophical system Sāṅkhya or mostly it signifies absolute knowledge or truth that is determinable by buddhi (as in 2.39), apparently both are used together. In this way, Sāṅkhya refers to jñāna yoga, however it's not exactly jñāna yoga.
As for Sāṅkhya yoga, it's the same as jñāna yoga, just different names.

Comment: The word Sānkhya comes from the roots *Sāṅ* , meaning “complete,” and *khyā* , meaning “to know.” So "Sānkhya" means the “complete analytical knowledge of something".The Sankhya Darshan, which is one of the six philosophical treatises in Indian philosophy, makes an analytical enumeration of the entities in cosmos. [1/3]

Comment: It lists twenty-four entities: pañch-mahābhūta (earth, water, fire, air, and sky), pañch tanmātrā (the five abstract qualities of matter—taste, touch, smell, sound, and sight), pañch karmendriya (five working senses), pañch jñānendriya (five knowledge senses), mind, ahankār (the entity created by the evolution of mahān), mahān (the entity created by evolution of prakṛiti), prakṛiti (the primordial form of the material energy). Apart from these is puruṣh or the Ātman, which tries to enjoy prakṛiti, and gets bound in it. [2/3]

Comment: Shri Krishna has just explained to Arjun another form of Sānkhya, which is the analytical knowledge of the immortal Ātman.[3/3]

Comment: Jnana normally refers to any kind of cognition but in the context of jnana-yoga, it refers only to the realization of the essential nature of self as identical with the Brahman called  Brahma-jnana or  atma-jnana.Jnana-yoga  is  not  only  the  process  of  knowing  but  is  a  sadhana  and involves  sadhana -sadhya  relationship.  Jnana  is  the  sadhana,  and realization  of  identity  with  Brahman  is  the  sadhya. [4]

Comment: Now If you have sincerely read verses 1-39 of the 2nd chap of BG you will come to know that Shri Krishna here is not really trying to convey the relationship between individual Atman(Jivatman) and Brahman, rather he explains to Arjuna the true nature of Atman as being deathless, imperishable and eternal....[5]

Comment: @Bingming so what's the difference between, Sāṅkhya and Sāṅkhya yoga?

Comment: Here, the connotation of sankya, in Gita , should not be misinterpreted for the sankya darshana(kapila Rishi). Here in Gita, sankya connotes moksha shaastra aka Brahma Vidya.Lord says the Brahma Vidya- shaastra pertaining to tattva Gyan (here sankya) is already imparted in prev. verses ( Sankye budhihi abihitha(imparted)..After having elucidated the Brahma Vidya , (ultimate purushartha) , Lord proceeds to detail on the saadhana(karma yoga) the precursor to attain Sankye budhihi. So the attitude with which karma needs to be carried out is explained further in Karma yoga, upcoming chapter

Answer (score 2):

The Gita verse 2.39 is given below:

> O Arjuna! What has been described to you is the Truth according to the
> Samkhya (the path of knowledge). Listen now to the teaching of Yoga
> (the path of selfless action combined with devotion) by practicing
> which the bondage of Karma is overcome.

**Gita 2.39**

> In the Gita passage under discussion, though this Samkhya and Yoga
> nomenclatures are used, the words practically mean what in modern
> Vedantic parlance we call Jnana-Yoga and Bhakti mixed Karma Yoga. So
> the verse has to be understood as meaning: I have given you the
> understanding, the conviction, which enlightenment (Jnana or Samkhya)
> gives of the real nature of man - of his essence, the Atman. Now I
> shall declare to you another way of attaining it, the Yoga or
> Karma-mixed Bhakti, which consists in performing all actions without
> attachments as devoted offering to the Divine, and in practicing love
> of Him and getting one's mind absorbed in Him through concentration
> (Samadhi). The idea is to cultivate devotion to God and dedicate
> oneself and all one's actions to Him, as His servant and devotee. If
> one practices this discipline in life, the Supreme Being bestows the
> knowledge of the devotee's true relation with His being - the
> awareness of being part and parcel of the Satchidananda. Sri
> Ramakrishna illustrates this by an analogy. A very faithful servant
> serves his Master for long and pleases him immensely by his love and
> loyalty. The master, out of intense love and consideration for him,
> puts him on his own seat, sating, 'You are myself; sit on it.' Just
> like that, supreme knowledge of one's spiritual identity (or intimacy)
> is what comes out of the Lord's grace for a Jiva who serves and
> surrenders to Him through love and service.

**Swami Tapasyananda's commentary on Gita 2.39**

Comment: Great answer with best analogy that explains !